# No DesignTimeAgent found

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am getting this strange error: No DesignTimeAgent found.
This happens on the EU2 region, with an paid Dialogflow account. If I try to export / import into the US region, this problem does not exist.

It is a no brainer to switch to US region.

Somebody knowing what I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
$intentsClient = new IntentsClient([
            'credentials' => storage_path('auth/<project-id>.json'),
        ]);

$parent = $intentsClient->agentName("<project-id>");
$intents = $intentsClient->listIntents($parent);
```

```
  Google\ApiCore\ApiException 

  {
    "message": "com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No DesignTimeAgent found for project '<project-id>'.",
    "code": 5,
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "details": []
}

  at vendor/google/gax/src/ApiException.php:139
```

Of course  is in my code replaced with the corresponding project.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a location `europe-west2` to `intentsClient` to use EU2 agent. [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region).

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error and resolved by switching region from AS to US. I guess some implementations are different from US region and other regions.

Comment: Yeah found that solution too, if I switch to US not a problem at all. But in this case it MUST be hosted in EU region.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. When I try clear and recreate the project and agent with US region and time, it works and won't report "No DesignTimeAgent found" anymore. But I still need to figure out how to use EU2 agent